# Python PDB set_trace not working

Tags: python, pdb

The program stops properly where expected, but I don't get the pdb prompt. Hitting "c" continues the program as expected.

I've checked stdout and it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was launching the program with something like

```
python program.py 2>&1 | tee out.log
```

Piping the output to tee was causing the issue.